# Matching a rule in the middle of any number of other rules

Tags: parsing, antlr, predicate, greedy

I'm working on a data definition language that uses braces to identify hierarchy.

```
typeA idS
{
    paramX = value
    typeB idT
    {
        paramY = value
    }       
}
```

There are a large number of different rules to validate what params and child types are valid for blocks of a certain type.

I would like to add functionality to allow a special block type to be placed around *any* existing block or set of name/value pairs.

```
BLOCK
{
    typeA idS
    {
        BLOCK
        {
            paramX = value
        }
        BLOCK
        {       
            typeB idT
            {
                paramY = value
            }
        }       
    }
 }
```

Is there a way to create a block that allows anything inside of it without having to specifically add BLOCK support to every existing type and without losing the parser check that the child param/type is valid for the given parent

I've tried using wildcards, greedy and non-greedy to no avail.

```
block: BLOCK '{' (options {greedy=false;} : .* ) '}'
```

Other answers suggest a syntactic predicate could solve it, but I'm unable to figure out how to use them (link to any online source would be appreciated).

Is there a way to do this without touching all the other rules?  (Hopefully not requiring many BLOCK_subtypes to keep the parent/child checking intact).  I'm concerned about readability and maintenance hassle.

Thanks

Comment: Yes.  Generally in the form:  
    type_param_list: PARAM value | otherType_defn
    type_defn : TYPE ID '{' type_param_list* '}';

Comment: The issue is I have dozens of types and hundreds of params organized in all sorts of combinations.  I could manually add BLOCK rules around them all, but I'm trying to avoid it.  Especially in order to keep the child in the context of the parent I'd need to add
`type_a_block: BLOCK '{' type_a_defn '}';
type_a_param_block: BLOCK '{' type_a_param_list '}';
type_a_defn: TYPE_A '{' (type_a_param_list | type_a_param_block )* '}` for every type.  I have little experience with ANTLR, but it feels that this is solvable in some sexy way.

Comment: Because then you can add invalid child types in a block.  If A(B(C)) and X(Y(Z)) is valid *and* BLOCK(A|B|C|X|Y|Z) is valid then A(BLOCK(Z)) is valid.

Comment: I don't see any other way than adding these blocks around each rule manually.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it needs multiple passes.

In the first pass, you could basically just parse the blocks and the data without doing any validation, with something like

```
blockType: BLOCK OPEN_BRACE type CLOSE_BRACE -> (BLOCK type);
blockParam: BLOCK OPEN_BRACE param CLOSE_BRACE -> (BLOCK param);
type: blockType | (typeName idName OPEN_BRACE param CLOSE_BRACE ->
                 (TYPE typeName idName param));
param: blockParam | (paramName EQUALS value -> (PARAM paramName value));
```

That would produce an AST that would be the input for the second pass.  In there, you would need rules like

```
paramA: (PARAM paramNameA value) | (BLOCK paramA);
typeB: (TYPE typeNameB idNameB paramB) | (BLOCK typeB);
```

The block structure intrudes into all of your rules, but it is doing so in a standard way.  You could probably even write something to modify your grammar file to add it.

It is also possible that you might want to use a preprocessor.  Something that replaces BLOCK { and the matching } with a special, otherwise invalid string would not be hard to write.  Each rule would then have the form BLOCK_START? stuff BLOCK_END?.  You should be able to add actions to ensure that you do not get a start without an end, but if the preprocessor is working (and rejecting the actual special text), that should not be possible.

All of this is probably more intrusive than you wanted, but the construct is fairly intrusive.

I am assuming that the extra tags actually trigger some sort of special processing.  If they are just syntactical sugar, then either solution is localized.  The preprocessor would just remove the BLOCK text.  The AST solution would generate the same AST, whether it matched the BLOCK or the naked statement.

Comment: The block sections are used to add context to segments of the main text.  Think of it as highlighted sections.  BLOCK in reality is a rule that has it's own tokens and sub-rules. How did you see the multiple passes being linked together?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question about linking the passes together.  You need a driver program to run the parser.  You pass your input text to the parser.  That returns an AST, which you pass to the tree walker.  I believe that Antr4 does not have tree walkers, in which case you have to use the visitor pattern that replaces it.  (I haven't used antlr4, so I'm less clear on how that works.)

Comment: I was referring to passing the AST off to the tree walker.  But I didn't know it at the time.